# Can 2 Oracle database instances listen on the same port on the same machine

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, listener, oracle12c

I have installed windows 7 64 bit os on my machine and installed oracle 12c database on the machine. Database software got installed properly and i'm able to connect using sql developer client. The database instance is listening on port 1521.  I have also installed oracle xe 11g edition. During the installation i did not get any errors and I got the message that installation is successful and complete. However, when i try to access it using sqldeveloper tool, the listener seem to be refusing the connection. How can i make both xe and 12c work on the same machine. Please let me know your suggestions.

How can i make them work both at the same time. I have seen cases where 2 instances use same port on the same machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you?  Sure.  You'd just need to have a single listener that listens for both databases.  Should you?  You're talking about "my machine", so I'm guessing this is a local laptop/ personal desktop.  My bias would be to have one of the two listen on 1522 (or some other random port) so that the two installs are as separate as possible.  In a local development environment, it's useful to not have to worry about screwing up the 11g environment when you tinker with the 12c environment (and vice versa).

Comment: You said,...Can you? Sure.  but how come the client connection has been declined with the below error

Comment: I'm not sure what "below error" you're referring to.  Presumably, you installed one listener in each Oracle Home.  You can't have two different listeners listening on the same port.  You can modify your configuration so that the 12c listener is listening for both the 12c database and the 11g database and shut down the 11g listener.  But that means that you've introduced a dependency between the Oracle Homes that I would guess you don't want in a development environment.  Hence my guess that you'll be happier in the long run letting one of the two listen on 1522.

Comment: Sorry i have hit enter before i pasted the error i got java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: XE doesn't give me an option to configure the listener. Could you point me to the link to reconfigure the xe listener or configure a new one

Comment: If you want to have one listener, it would need to be the 12c listener that would listen for both databases.  If you want to move one listener to 1522, I'd strongly suggest moving the 12c listener.  Were it me, I'd leave the XE database in the most vanilla configuration possible.